# SQL Server Results to File Creates extra lines at end

Tags: sql-server, linebreaks

When I route the output of my queries to a file, there are one or two blank lines at the bottom.  When I run the query though SSMS (2008 or 2012), I get two extra blank lines.  When I run the query through SQLCMD, I get 1 extra blank line.  How do I get rid of them?

Example (using SSMS):

```
Set NoCount on
Select '1' as 'One'
```

The output of this query in the file is:

```
One
1
(blank line)
(blank line)
```

or hex `4F 6E 65 0D 0A 31 0D 0A 0D 0A`

The extra line(s) at the bottom are causing problems with steps that use the output as input.

Is there a parameter I can Set at the beginning of the query?

Is it a database option?

Comment: I'm not sure there is a way to disable the extra blank lines from the SSMS end of things (I've found "results to file" options/control to be very limited in my experiences). Perhaps use a batch that uses `SQLCMD` to dump to the file, and then use a variation of `findstr "." input.txt > output.txt` to strip all blank lines from it before passing to the next step?  You may have also have to go further and find a way to remove the line-feed off the last line of text.

Comment: I'd like to avoid any extra manipulation of the files because some of them are 1+ GB and growing.  But if I have to, findstr better than editing it manually.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Before writing into the file add one conditional split step. Double click the component and in the output name, give the name 'No Empty Row' and in the condition write `LEN(TRIM(One)) > 0`. Here One is column name this condition will remove those rows having nulls. Now link the output of conditional output to data file destination. Remember to choose **No Empty Row**. From this you can remove extra rows.

Comment: I think this would work if I were running through SSIS.  Unfortunately, SSIS is not an option for this process.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Format-List` in the command. For example

```
> sqlcmd -Q "Set NoCount on; Select '1' as 'One'"| Format-List | Out-String | ForEach-Object { $_.Trim() }
```