# Excel Data Connection Always Has 1 Extra Row

Tags: microsoft-excel, connection, csv, external-data

I have an Excel file with a data connection to another Excel workbook.  Every time that I refresh the connection, there seems to be one extra blank row in the table (with formulas, but there is no calculation).  No matter if I delete it in the source location or the destination, it happens after every refresh.

The source Excel file actually is another data connection to a CSV file.  It simply refreshes the text data, adds additional fields based on formulas calculated in the source and then saves.

So in essence, the progression is CSV (plain text) > Excel Source file (with fill-down formulas) > Excel destination file.

I am assuming that the issue is between the CSV and the Excel Source file, but I cannot figure out how to resolve it.

Comment: How was the CSV created?  Does the CSV file have an extra blank line at the end?  I have a situation where routing SQL Server output to a text file creates extra blank lines at the end of file. http://superuser.com/questions/1002299/sql-server-results-to-file-creates-extra-lines-at-end.  Your situation could be similar.

Comment: @B540Glenn Thank you for the response!  I read that when searching for solutions to this problem, but when I open the CSV in Excel there doesn't seem to be a blank line.  In the text file itself, it seems as if there might be so I guess the best temporary solution would be to write a quick VBA macro to delete it.